# Share folder content between two containers in same pod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Pod with two containers, Nginx and Rails. I want to share the public folder from the rails to the nginx container, but the public contains already files, I don't want the folder be empty.

Is there a way with a shared-volume?

I tried:

```
- name: rails-assets
    hostPath:
      path: /app/public
```

But im getting this error:

```
Error: failed to start container "nginx": Error response from daemon: {"message":"error while creating mount source path '/app/public': mkdir /app: read-only file system"}
Error syncing pod
Back-off restarting failed container
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I fixed that problem creating a shared-volument `shared-assets/` on the rails app. On the rails dockerfile I created a ENTRYPOINT with a bash script to copy the `public/` files on the `shared-assets/` folder. With this I can see the files now on the Nginx Container.

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: staging-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: staging
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: staging
        image: some/container:v5
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/
          name: rails-socket
        - mountPath: /app/shared-assets
          name: rails-assets
      - name: nginx
        image: some/nginx:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/
          name: rails-socket
        - mountPath: /app
          name: rails-assets
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: app-backend-secret
      volumes:
      - name: rails-socket
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: rails-assets
        emptyDir: {}
```

And the script ENTRYPOINT:

```
cp -r /app/public/ /app/shared-assets/
```